# Jekyll theme is working on local, but not working on remote

Tags: jekyll

I forked [this theme](https://github.com/iwiedenm/jekyll-theme-massively-src) and created a simple pages, modified some css files - setting fonts for specific tags or disable italic on subheadings.

It works like a charm in local. But when I commit the files and push the repo, It shows contents but the design things are gone! I mean, It shows only html contents.

This is the page on local environment:

[image: local]

And this is the page on the remote server..?

[image: remote]

I can use basic tags and change some properties of tags in CSS, but I don't know about more details.. Could you please give me some kinds of guide or how to fix this problem?

Edit -- Here is my git repository:

https://github.com/soldier4443/soldier4443.github.io

Comment: git repo url is usefull for debug.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Sorry about that.. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***_config.yml***, remove `baseurl: "/blog"` to read `baseurl: ""`.

Comment: Oh.. You are my lifesaver! Indeed, It was not worked in the local environment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

FYI- if your theme is working locally but not working remotely(OP didn't have an issue with this, though this was my mistake), make sure that the remote repository is named .github.io

More info. from the official documentation: "GitHub Pages are initially configured to live under the username.github.io subdomain, which is why repositories must be named this way even if a custom domain is being used."

source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/